# SQL To check if the room is available between the dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question in reference to a query to the database. 
I have this table:

[image]

In another window, i have a form with start and end date inputs and I want to do a sql to confirm if the room 23 is available between this dates, every day.
I try with this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM this_table 
WHERE room_type_id=23 
AND date="2018-03-06 00:00:00" 
AND date="2018-03-07 00:00:00" 
AND date="2018-03-08 00:00:00" 
AND date="2018-03-09 00:00:00"
```

This query doesn't work because is checking if any row has all the dates.

My question is: How can i check if the room is available on this days?

Comment: A specific date value can never be equal to all those different dates. Count the dates available and see if all 4 are there.

Comment: Have you tried changing AND by OR?  `room_type=23 AND (date OR date OR ...)`

Comment: I'm sure you know that the date cannot be yesterday,today and tomorrow in same time, and your database structure is not specified in your question. please explain your question ...

Comment: What do you store in the table "this_table" the room booked or available ?

Comment: Are you looking for a yes/no answer or an actual list of the dates that are available based on the list you pass to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will answer your particular question with yes or no. I'm not sure it's useful since the date search values are all specific in a hard-coded list.

```
select coalesce(max('no'), 'yes') as available
from tbl t           
where room_type_id = 23 and
    dt in ("2018-03-06 00:00:00", "2018-03-07 00:00:00", 
           "2018-03-08 00:00:00", "2018-03-09 00:00:00");
```

If the sense of your logic is intended to find *at least one open* date then you might try something like this:

```
select case when count(*) = 4 then 1 else 0 end as whatever_this_means
from tbl t
where room_type_id = 23 and
    dt in ("2018-03-06 00:00:00", "2018-03-07 00:00:00", 
           "2018-03-08 00:00:00", "2018-03-09 00:00:00");
```

The problem is going to be that you've hard-coded the value 4 now which is tied to the number of dates in the list later in the query. There are ways to handle this more dynamically but it's not entirely clear from your question the best way to do that.

Comment: Hi shawnt00, thank you for your response. That's exactly what I'm looking for, but this query doesn`t work for me. I'm getting "no" if any date of array exist and "yes" if no one exist.

Comment: For example: If ("2018-03-08 00:00:00", "2018-03-09 00:00:00") are in this table, i get "no" but if one of this dates exist and not the other, i get "no" too. Then I get "yes" only if all the dates not exist.

Comment: "No" means not available. I thought you wanted to confirm that a room reservation exists for *none* of the dates.

Comment: In this table are the available rooms, and i want to know if are available in all this days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using OR instead of AND between the dates?

```
SELECT * FROM this_table 
WHERE room_type_id=23 AND 
(date="2018-03-06 00:00:00" OR
date="2018-03-07 00:00:00" OR
date="2018-03-08 00:00:00" OR
date="2018-03-09 00:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

shawnt00 gives me a good idea. I modify a little this query changing the yes and no responses and it works for me.

```
select case when count(*) < 4 then 'no' else 'yes' end as available
from room_type_day t
where room_type_id = 23 and
    date in ("2018-03-07 00:00:00","2018-03-08 00:00:00","2018-03-09 00:00:00","2018-03-10 00:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you store room info inside db when somebody reserve it the every record show that the room is not empty at it's date, now if you have another table that store room names you can select rooms that not exists any date for them

```
SELECT room_id FROM rooms WHEN room_id NOT IN (SELECT room_id FROM reserveTable WHERE date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

but if you store empty rooms in db(it may be a dirty database ;-) ) you can select rooms that are between your dates,

```
SELECT room_id FROM reserveTable WHEN date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @ EndDate
```

finally, it depends to your database structure, and your form definition.
i hope this help you to find a good solution

Comment: Thank you Farrokh, I have this table to store the available rooms that Hotel, Hostel or accommodation manager want to sale. I get all the rooms near a location and i only want to do a subquery to verify if the rooms are available between this dates. But I have to verify if the guest can rent this room every selected days. 

If I try with this query's, I'm getting this error:
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

If 'this_table' store available room then you can return 0 or 1 with this trick :

Count the number of days available :

```
SELECT room_type_id, Count(*) as Av_days
FROM this_table
WHERE room_type_id=23 AND date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @ EndDate GROUP BY room_type_id
```

Then test the equality :

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(@EndDate, @StartDate) = Av_days )
 FROM
  (SELECT room_type_id, Count(*) as Av_days
  FROM this_table
   WHERE room_type_id=23 AND date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @ EndDate
  GROUP BY room_type_id) t
```

If you the same number of days, it will return 1 else 0

Answer (score -1):

You need to use OR instead of AND. Your statement will only return a result if room 23 is equal to all 4 of those dates listed.

```
SELECT * FROM this_table 
WHERE room_type_id=23 
AND 
(
   date="2018-03-06 00:00:00" 
OR date="2018-03-07 00:00:00" 
OR date="2018-03-08 00:00:00" 
OR date="2018-03-09 00:00:00"
)
```

Comment: this will return 23 if one of dates exist, and i guess it was wrong because he(or she) should check all dates...(according to question and sample)

Comment: Hi Farrokh, you are on right I want to check if all the dates exist. I only want a true or false response if is possible.